# Can I use the Access Database Engine 2010 from a C++ program built with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ms-access, mfc, dao

Is there a way to get DAO to connect with Access Database Engine 2010 in an MFC C++ application built with Visual Studio 2017? I'm working on a legacy application that needs to read Access 97 MDB databases and from what I've read online, support for these was dropped in Access Database Engine 2016. I have both versions of the database engine installed on my PC, but the application built with VS 2017 only seems to connect to the 2016 version. When the application was built with VS 2015 it worked fine. Is there a way to make my application use the 2010 version instead so I can open these old databases? (Going back to VS 2015 is not an option)

Answer (score 4):

Every copy of windows - going back to windows 98SE has a copy of the JET (mdb) Access database engine installed. So if you looking to only read and use mdb files - then the built in default copy of JET data engine should work. It is possible that later editions of windows have a newer version of JET and thus can't read a97 mdb files, but I believe the default engine installed on windows can read such files.

So you don't need to, and should not have to install a copy of the data engine. You can use either .NET ODBC provider, or you can use the .net oleDB provider. Both of these providers should be able to consume and use and open mdb files without any additonal software being installed on your part.

You DO however have to ensure that your project is set (forced) to use x86 compile, and do NOT deploy with "any CPU" or of course x64 bits, since as such, you can't use + consume x32 bit .dll's and software if your project is running as x64 bits.

Edit: so to be sure that you using this older and pre-installed data engine? Simply don't use "ACE" in your connection string. The built in .net (Visual Studio) connection builder WILL let you set/choose the "JET" (older) mdb data engine as opposed to the newer (ACE) accDB data engine.

You see this option here:

[image]

And then:

[image]

So from above, if you choose JET as opposed to ACE? Then you using the 20 year copy of JET that is installed by defualt on every copy of windows since windows 98SE. And this choice should allow you to open a97 mdb files, and the BONUS feature is that you don't need to install the ACE data engine, nor connectivity component packs either - it is pre-installed on windows.

if you going to use accDB format? Then you MUST install ACE. However, JET is and should already be installed.

Edit:
I see that you were talking about c++ and NOT c#/vb.net. However the above advice still holds. It will thus still be your choice to use ODBC or oleDB in your code - and as noted both should work.

Comment: Thanks, yes its x86, but this application is in MFC C++ and uses the DAO library. The info you've provided seems to be for .NET. To be more specific, the problem with opening these old MDBs is occurring when calling DAOWorkspace::OpenDatabase().

Comment: Indeed - I did edit and follow up that this was not .net. I am not sure if I have a mdb in 97 format to test. If you can open newer mdb file and not a older one? Then JET 4.0 may well not be able to open the a97 mdb files. So check if you can open "some" mdb files and not all. I try and check/see if I have a a97 mdb file and can open it with JET 4.0 - you should be able to - I am open to being corrected here. edit: this is dao 3.6 then - it should work.

Comment: I can open Access 2000 MDBs fine with this code, just not Access 97 ones. When I set the connection string in the DAOWorkspace::OpenDatabase() call to anything other than an empty string, I get an error which says "ODBC--connection to '<Database path>' failed."

Comment: Ouch!! Since you CAN open a2000 mdb's, then you have to dig up a older copy of DAO. I  am not sure how easy that is going to be. DAO and mdb file format ONLY goes to Access 2003. In 2007 they changed over to ACE. So I am surprised that you can't open a97 formats. I thinking maybe this is a access 2.0 mdb!!! So Access 2003 (and JET) could always open a97 mdb files. I wonder if that mdb file is damaged? I think ACE 2010 was the last version to open a97, but pure JET vs ACE? That should work to my knowledge.

Comment: Just to be clear? I noted and mentioned that Access 2003 (17 years ago) was the LAST version of JET for Access. And that version could open a97 mdb files. And even windows 10? Well, JET is that same JET 4.0 from 2003 - and thus I am surprised that you can't open that mdb file. As noted, perhaps the mdb is a95, or gasp, Access 2.0 from 1992!!! - So, JET should be able to consume that database. As noted, ACE will not. While both ACE and JET do install DAO providers, it is possbile that the .dll's were munged or upgraded to ACE "dao", but mdb files and a97 ones should open.

Comment: The Access 97 MDB file is not damaged because I can open it in an earlier version of this same application that was built with VS 2015, running on the same PC. The only issue I have is with the version of the program built with VS 2017. I believe the VS 2015 build of the program is using Access Database Engine 2010 and new one built with VS 2017 is using Access Database Engine 2016, both of which are installed on my machine in 32 bit versions. But the 2016 version is known to have dropped support for Access 97 MDBs. That's why I want to use the older one if I can...

Comment: As I stated, you better off to use JET and not use 2010 Access or even 2016 Access. The base built in version of JET should be able to open that mdb file - no need for Access 2010, 2016 or even 2000 for that matter.  The fact that 2010 is entering into this discussion at all suggest that we not using JET but in fact ACE.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but as its a legacy application I'm just trying to make the minimum change to get it to work. It sounds like I'll probably have to just way some external tool to convert the Access 97 MDBs to Access 2000 ones though since this is all looking too hard.

Comment: Well, you could install the Access 2010 "office" connectivity package. That would get you a 2010 DAO. I would check the "imports" and reference path you are using to the dao360 .dll. I suspect it "might" be overwritten by office installs.  As I stated, zero installing of software should be required - and the default dao should work. The link to the 2010 connective pack is this one - you could try this:https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255